# error with updating database in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update one property in my firebase database but there is error appeared its 
Error:Reference.update failed:First argument must be an object containing the children to replace

```
analysis = (actionid)=>{


    //check if it is't the first command
    console.log('before definition of flage')
    var flag=false;
    console.log('hiii')
    firebase.database().ref('userActions/').once ('value',(snap)=>{ 
        console.log("iafter definition ")
        snap.forEach((child)=>{
            if(child.val().userID===firebase.auth().currentUser.uid && child.val().ActionID== actionid){
            plus=parseInt(child.val().Repetition)+1;
            console.log("before first use")
            flag=true;
            console.log("before first use 2")
            firebase.database().ref('userActions/'+child.key).update(

                Repetition=plus, 

            ).then(() => {
                console.log('inserted the update')
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error)
            });
         } })
    }
    ).finally(()=>{
        if(flag===false)
        this.insertUserAction();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
        firebase.database().ref('userActions/'+child.key).update(
            Repetition=plus, 
        )
```

It looks like you meant to pass an object instead, using curly braces to define the object containing the properties to update:

```
        firebase.database().ref('userActions/'+child.key).update({
            Repetition=plus, 
        })
```